# Cannot read binary file created in Java using Python

Tags: java, python, memory, mapping, binary-data

I have created a binary file using Java and memory mapping. It contains a list of integers from 1 to 10 million:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

public class MemoryMapWriter {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException {
  File f = new File("file.bin");
  f.delete();

  FileChannel fc = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw").getChannel();

  long bufferSize=64*1000;
  MappedByteBuffer mem =fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, bufferSize);

  int start = 0;
  long counter=1;
  long HUNDREDK=100000;
  long startT = System.currentTimeMillis();
  long noOfMessage = HUNDREDK * 10 * 10; 
  for(;;)
  {         
   if(!mem.hasRemaining())
   {
    start+=mem.position();
    mem =fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, start, bufferSize);
   }
   mem.putLong(counter); 
   counter++;
   if(counter > noOfMessage )
    break; 
  }
  long endT = System.currentTimeMillis();
  long tot = endT - startT;
  System.out.println(String.format("No Of Message %s , Time(ms) %s ",noOfMessage, tot)) ;  
 }
```

then I have tried to read it using Python and memory mapping:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import shutil
import re
import mmap

a=np.memmap("file.bin",mode='r',dtype='int64')
print(a[0:9])
```

but printing first ten element, this is the result:

```
[ 72057594037927936, 144115188075855872, 216172782113783808,
  288230376151711744, 360287970189639680, 432345564227567616,
  504403158265495552, 576460752303423488, 648518346341351424,
  720575940379279360]
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3):

You have a byte-order problem.  `72057594037927936` in binary is `0x0100000000000000`, `144115188075855872` is `0x0200000000000000`, etc.

Java is writing `long`s to the buffer in big-endian order (most significant byte first) and Python is interpreting the resulting byte stream in little-endian order (least significant byte first).

One simple fix is to change the Java buffer's `ByteOrder` attribute:

```
mem.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
```

Or tell Python to use big-endian order.  Python doesn't seem to have an analogous option for its memmap functions, so this will probably require using [`struct.unpack_from`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack_from) to specify the byte order.

Comment: Thank you. mem.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN); solves